# glib's GAsyncQueue equivalent for C++?

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, glib

[glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) has a data structure called `GAsyncQueue`, which allows inter-thread communication with no semaphores/locks/etc., and even makes trivial the task of implementing a producer/consumer solution. If two different threads push data to a `GAsyncQueue` structure, the `push` function internally implements the mutually exclusive access to the queue; more awesomely, if a thread calls the `pop` function, and there is no data there, the calling thread blocks until some data is pushed into the queue by some other thread. All of this is done in a thread-safe manner, transparently to the developer.

As much as I like it, though, this library was built for C, and there might be better alternatives for higher level languages. I'm thinking about using glib anyway, but it feels odd to use a C library in a C++ code...

So, the question is: is there a C++ recommended equivalent for glib? More specifically, is there a more recommended C++ library that provides the same functionality as `GAsyncQueue`?

Comment: It's pretty easy to write one with a `std::queue`, a `std::mutex` and a `std::condition_variable`

Comment: @JonathanWakely sure, I agree with you that it'd be easy, but I'd much rather use a well-tested (and probably optimized) implementation of a message queue than roll out my own from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using C in a C++ program (after all, C++ implementation is heavily based on C runtime, for example C++11 thread support cannot live without pthread library, at least on UNIX®-like platforms). I would definitely not choose the tool/library only and entirely basing on the language it is written in. But if you must use something else, then glib is not the only library in the world that provides provides asynchronous message passing (by the way, it doesn't really look like it supports IPC). Anyhow, here is a list of C++ frameworks that immediately come to my mind (in random order, as random as my thoughts):

- [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org)
- [Boost MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/mpi.html)
- [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html)

Each one has its own strengths and weaknesses, and which one to use really depends on what exactly your requirements are. I can only recommend you to pay attention to overall application architecture and how well the asynchronous message passing would fit into all of the components of your application. For example, in more or less complex applications that involve more than simple message passing, such asynchronous queues are oftentimes integrated with the event notification mechanisms in use (for example, OSX is built around [kqueue/GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Good point on IPC, I meant inter-thread communication without explicitly using synchronization primitives. Edited accordingly.